# Expression for polynomial of companion matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, control-theory, companion-matrices

I am rather stuck on an exercise concerning the companion/controllability matrix (the exercise stems from a course in control theory).

Given the companion matrix 
\begin{equation}
A=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
-a_1 & -a_2 & -a_3 & ... & -a_{n-1}&-a_n\\
1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 &0 & ... & 0 &0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 &0 & ... & 1 &0
\end{array}
\right).
\end{equation}
to the equation $a(s)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_is^{n-i}$. Show for another polynomial

$$g(s)=\sum_{i=0}^n g_is^{n-i}$$

that

$$g(A)=((A^{n-1})'c'\: ...\: A'c' \text{  } c')'$$
where $c'=(g_1, ..., g_n)'$ such that $c'$ is a column vector. Note that I am using the somewhat strange convention of $'$ as tranpose.

EDIT: I forgot to write, $a_0=1, g_0=0$.

I've been playing around a bit with the inverse $g(A)^{-1}$ but am not sure it exists and have also been trying to factor out the $c'$ but to no avail.

Any suggestion or help otherwise is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, we have $a_0 = 1$, and $g_0 = 0$. Otherwise, I don't see how this can make sense.  Also, I assume you mean $g(A')$ rather than $g(A)$.

First, prove that whatever the answer is should be a linear function of $c'$.  That is, $g(A')$ is a linear function of the coefficients of $g$.

Now, it suffices to prove that this holds on a basis.  Let the vectors $e_j$ denote the canonical basis (so, for example, $e_1 = (1,0,\dots,0)'$). It's enough to prove that the formula holds when $c' = e_j$, which is to say that $g(s) = s^{n-j}$.  That is, we need to show that for each $j$,
$$
(A^{n-j})' = \pmatrix{(A^{n-1})' e_{j} & (A^{n-2})' e_{j} & \cdots & e_{j}}
$$

Now, we need to important properties of $A$:

1. For $i = 0,\dots,n-1$, we have
   $$
   A' e_{n-i} = e_{n-(i+1)}
   $$
2. The desired identity holds for $j=n$, which is to say $g(s) = 1$.  That is:
   $$
   I = \pmatrix{(A^{n-1})'e_n & (A^{n-2})'e_n & \cdots & e_n}
   $$

It is notable (but not of use to us in itself) that $a(A) = 0$.

To finish the proof, we need to show that the identity holds for $j=n-i$ for each of $i = 1,\dots,n-1$ (property 2 was the identity for $i=0$). That is, we need to show the identity holds for $g(s) = s^i$. That is, we need to show
$$
(A^i)' = \pmatrix{(A^{n-1})' e_{n-i} & (A^{n-2})' e_{n-i} & \cdots & e_{n-i}}
$$
For each of $i = 0,\dots,n-1$, noting that we've already shown it for $i=0$.  We can prove that this holds using *induction* as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
(A^{i+1})' &=
A' (A^i )'
\\ & =
A' \pmatrix{(A^{n-1})' e_{n-i} & (A^{n-2})' e_{n-i} & \cdots & e_{n-i}} 
\\ & =
\pmatrix{(A^{n})' e_{n-i} & (A^{n-1})' e_{n-i} & \cdots & A' e_{n-i}} 
\\ & =
\pmatrix{(A^{n-1})' (A'e_{n-i}) & (A^{n-2})' (A'e_{n-i}) & \cdots & (A' e_{n-i})} 
\\ & =
\pmatrix{(A^{n-1})' e_{n-(i+1)} & (A^{n-2})' e_{n-(i+1)} & \cdots & e_{n-(i+1)}}
\end{align}
$$
The conclusion follows.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer as soon as I've had the chance to work through given that I understand it fully at that point.

Comment: my answer is a bit hard to read as is; I'll try to organize it a bit if I find the time

Comment: Also, you are correct about $a_0=1, g_0=0$. I rewrote the original question a bit and forgot to align my definitions with the original ones.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: I seem to have a mistake in my work since I forgot a ' at some point.  Not sure if I can make sense of this just yet.

Comment: Ah! Your formula should be for $g(A')$, not $g(A)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful replies. I think I have actually learned quite a bit from your answer! Accepted.